# MSChart X-axis is starting from -1 instead of 0

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I posted this earlier but have just registered on the site today,

I tried using the

```
  YourChartArea.AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
```

but its still starting at -1 :(

I even tried incremented my Xaxis value (value +1), the data is plotted at point 2 on the X-axis, yet the X-axis is still starting from -1.

Any other suggestions please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

I think this may help:

Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;

Comment: Thank you so much I cant select to mark as right answer as I just registered and need like 15points? but your solution was perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.isstartedfromzero.aspx), that property

> Gets or sets a flag which indicates
>   whether the minimum value of the axis
>   will be automatically set to zero if
>   all data point values are positive

Since you are getting a -1, I'd wager that you have some negative values.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I stated a sec ago that it did work, so my apologies, I also could not mark as correct solution as I dont have enough points to do so, I just registered about 10 mins ago, and greatful I did.Thank you both :)